# How to call a method on a generated input field c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a newbie when it comes to c# so bear with me :).

I've made a form in asp.net and I'm trying to validate it with a RequiredFieldValidator.
My problem is that the input fields are generated with a for loop.

My question is how can i validate these input fields, is there some way to 'pass an object' like in java?

Edit:
The table in which the fields are generated:

```
      <asp:Table id="newPatienttbl" 
      GridLines="Both" 
      HorizontalAlign="Center" 
      Font-Size="8pt" 
      CellPadding="5"
      CellSpacing="0"
      Runat="server"/>
```

How i generate my input fields.

```
        TableRow row = null;
        TableCell cell = null;
        TextBox tb = null;
        foreach (DataColumn column in patientData.Columns)
        {
            row = new TableRow();
            cell = new TableCell();

            if (column.ColumnName.Equals("ZVID"))
                cell.Text = "Zorgverzekeraar";
            else
                cell.Text = column.ColumnName;

            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();

            if (!column.ColumnName.Equals("ZVID"))
            {
                tb = new TextBox();
                cell.Controls.Add(tb);
            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList dd = new DropDownList();
                dd.ID = column.ColumnName;
                dd.DataSource = zorgData;
                dd.DataValueField = "ZVID";
                dd.DataTextField = "Naam";


                dd.DataBind();
                cell.Controls.Add(dd);
            }

            cell.ID = column.ColumnName+"Cell";
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            newPatienttbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: please show how you generate the fields!

Comment: Added the code that generates the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code with something like this :

```
        string addedControlId;
        if (!column.ColumnName.Equals("ZVID"))
        {
            tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Id= column.ColumnName;
            cell.Controls.Add(tb);
            addedControlId = tb.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList dd = new DropDownList();
            dd.ID = column.ColumnName;
            dd.DataSource = zorgData;
            dd.DataValueField = "ZVID";
            dd.DataTextField = "Naam";


            dd.DataBind();
            cell.Controls.Add(dd);
            addedControlId = dd.Id;
        }
        RequiredFieldValidator val = new RequiredFieldValidator{

            ControlToValidate = addedControlId,
            ErrorMessage = "Shame on you, you did not fill this value"

        }
        cell.Controls.Add(val);
```

However, your code make me think you should move a databound control, like [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datatable.aspx) or [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx). You will benefits the use of templating your items.

Comment: Thanks a lot, im not used to the way of 'adding' something in c#, which is probably the biggest issue...